# Using css to hide scrollbar but enable scroll on Firefox

Tags: css, html, firefox

Hello everyone, I want to make a navbar like apple.com on phone screen. 
Now, I success make that on Safari and Chrome, and run well on both of them.

Code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/me09ag6k/)

Main css like this:

```
    ul::-webkit-scrollbar { 
        display: none; 
    }
    ul{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 70px;
        list-style-type:none;
        white-space:nowrap;
        overflow-x:auto;
        font-size: 0px;
    }
    li{
        display:inline-block;
        background-color: gray;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
```

On Chrome and Safari, the scroll bar of x can hide, but on Firefox can't.

Can I fix it ane run on Firefox?
If have some solution, please let me know, thanks a lot .

Comment: A hacky way might be to increase padding-right by 17px and then increase margin-right by 17px as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the  [jquery nicescroll plugin](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll)

**Update**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/me09ag6k/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {$("ul").niceScroll();
$("ul").getNiceScroll().hide();});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think this is not what I want.